# What form does the Gibbons-Hawking term take before ADM decomposition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, boundary-terms

What form does the GBY term take before evaluated at the surface?

I know that for the Einstein-Hilbert action to have a well-posed variation, one must introduce the GBY term such that,

\begin{equation}
S=S_{EH}+S_{GBY}=\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} R +2\int d^3 x \sqrt\gamma K.
\end{equation}

So my question is, for
\begin{equation}
\int d^4 x\partial_\mu V^\mu = 2\int d^3 x \sqrt\gamma K.
\end{equation}
What is the explicit form of $V^\mu =V^\mu (g_{\mu\nu})$?

Comment: I think this is covered on the wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking%E2%80%93York_boundary_term

Comment: I think you got the idea in reverse. If you had just the EH term, you'd get the $\int$ (divergence) term that you're talking about. This can be converted into a surface integral. The idea is then to include $(-1)$ $\times$ this surface term into the original action such that any boundary contribution vanishes and you're just left with the bulk EH part.

Comment: Eletie  and @Avantgarde
Thank you for the response. I have followed/derived both the contents of Wikipedia and other related textbooks.
For all I know, the GBY is necessary to eliminate \partial\delta g from the surface to make it well defined.
However, it seems that when defining one need to define a certain surface
I was just wondering if you can obtain GBY without doing so.
Since GBY is a surface term, I suspected it could be written in the form S=\partial_\mu V^\mu and thus my question

Comment: @KayS See chap 4 of Eric Poisson's book 'A Relativist's Toolkit'

Comment: @Avantgarde Yes I have read that book. My question is not about the derivation of the GBY term but whether the GBY can be written 4-dim covariantly.